# Always return user details as json every time user login in laravel 5

Tags: php, json, authentication, laravel-5

What I want to do is that,whenever a user request for login, a json response will provide,not the last url they request.

Example:
At first say user request for logged in with url

> http://localhost/example/public/index.php/auth/login

and I returned user details as json response.

Now consider user logout,then request for this page:

> http://localhost/example/public/index.php/business/all

so I am returning json

```
status: true
isLogin: false
msg: "Your session expired,login first"
requestError: [0]
```

Now he/she will try to login with the login url,
then after successful login, they are redirecting automaticaly to

http://localhost/example/public/index.php/business/all

but I don't want that, I want to return user details whenever user request for login..

consider that, I am new in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of this question. In **postLogin()** method of **AuthController**, laravel is redirecting with named route from session via intended method. Now I remove the intended method and redirect to a hard coded url. So every time user is request for login,he/she is redirecting to my url not intended url.